# Another regex expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for the next rules:

- should not start or end with a space
- should contain just letters (lower / upper), digits, @, single quotes, hyphens and spaces (spaces just inside, but not at the beginning and the end, as I already said)
- should contain at least one letter (lower or upper).

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried? what language do you use?

Comment: In which dialect of regex? To go into which command or programming language? "Another regex expression" implies you already have one, so what did you try for this one, and what problems did you have when trying that? Or did you just not try?

Comment: We are not here to do your home work for you if you can try and post what you've tried

Comment: JavaScript. Does it really matter guys? No, I don't have a current regex, I need one.

Comment: Do you have an example string that you need to match or anything at all to help us understand what it is that you want? And yes, it does matter, it would be pointless providing you with a python regex if you want JavaScript, it wouldn't work for you

Answer (score -1):

I think

^[^ ](?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)[a-zA-Z0-9@'\- ]*[^ ]$

should help you.

Comment: Your character class is missing a single quote as the OP also want to match that.

Answer (score -1):

> "Does it really matter guys?"

with regards to the dialect of regex: yes it does matter. Different languages may have different dialects. One example off the top of my head is that the RegEx library in PHP supports lookbehinds whereas RegEx library in JavaScript does not. This is why it is important for you to list the underlying language that you're using. Also for future reference, it is helpful for those wanting to answer your questions to provide us with sample input and sample matches from the input.

Using the information that you provided, this is also a question that I feel as though you should use RegEx *and* JavaScript to validate the input. Take a look at this example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var valid = "a1 - 'super' 1";
  var invalid1 = " a1 - 'super' 1"; //leading ws
  var invalid2 = "a1 - 'super' 1 "; //trailing ws
  var invalid3 = "a1 - 'super' 1?"; //invalid (?) char
  var invalid4 = "1 - '123'";       //no letters
  
  console.log(valid + ": " + validation(valid));
  console.log(invalid1 + ": " + validation(invalid1));
  console.log(invalid2 + ": " + validation(invalid2));
  console.log(invalid3 + ": " + validation(invalid3));
}

function validation(input) {
  var acceptableChars = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z\d\s'-]/g);
  var containsLetter = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z]/);
  return input.length > 1 && input.trim().length == input.length && !acceptableChars.test(input) && containsLetter.test(input);
}
```